# evaluating MapboxGLManager.mapStyles

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, mapbox

I keep getting this error when trying to install Mapbox (found [here](https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl)) on my React-Native app. 
[image: Error]

My files are as follows:

[build.gradle](http://pastebin.com/860XUxjA)

[settings.gradle](http://pastebin.com/bWiB2hTY)

[MainActivity.java](http://pastebin.com/5TgCnsDq)

[AndroidManifest.xml](http://pastebin.com/Dm1iDLXr)

Answer (score 0):

In your build.gradle and settings.gradle, you've added wrong lines :

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-mapbox-gl') // <==== remove this line
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"
    compile project(':reactnativemapboxgl') // <=== missing this line
}
```

**settings.gradle**

Remove those two lines ...

```
include ':react-native-mapbox-gl'
project(':react-native-mapbox-gl').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-mapbox-gl/android')
```

... and replace them with these :

```
include ':reactnativemapboxgl'
project(':reactnativemapboxgl').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-mapbox-gl/android')
```

Comment: Actually now it's giving me the error I had before I got to this error, which is basically the same thing except now it says

`ExceptionsManager.js:61
Cannot read property 'mapStyles' of undefined
handleException @ ExceptionsManager.js:61
handleError @ InitializeJavaScriptAppEngine.js:122
reportFatalError @ error-guard.js:30
guardedLoadModule @ require.js:60
_require @ require.js:49
(anonymous function) @ require-0.js:1
executeApplicationScript @ debuggerWorker.js:18
onmessage @ debuggerWorker.js:33`